# Node.js,AWS SNS ,How can we send notification to multiple devices?

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

```
 `sns.createPlatformEndpoint({
      PlatformApplicationArn: '',
      Token: ['b6f5929c55dbb*****************f79647b632486ef3']
    },'
```

here,as **Token** accepts only string,we can give only one device token.But I need to send same notification to multiple devices.

any help can be really appreciated

Comment: Do you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The method you are invoking is used to create the endpoints on SNS, once you create, you will get this endpoint arn (AWS identifier). You should store these arn's in a database and then send the notification for them.